# Convergence in distribution of the $2SLS$ estimator for some $\pi = \frac{h}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: asymptotics, instrumental-variables

Consider the following IV model.

$$y_{1,i} = y_{2,i} \beta + u_i$$
$$y_{2,i} = z_{i}' \pi + v_{2,i}$$

with $(z_i', u_i, v_{2,i})$ iid and $\begin{pmatrix} 
u_i \\
v_{2,i}
\end{pmatrix} \sim N(0_{2x1},\Omega)$

I want to show that the 2SLS estimator $\hat{\beta}$ converges to a nondegenerate distribution for $\pi = \frac{h}{\sqrt{n}}$. I know that

$$\hat{\beta} = \beta + \frac{y_2' Z(Z'Z)^{-1}Z' u}{y_2' Z(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'y_2}$$

$$= \beta + \frac{\frac{y_2' Z}{\sqrt{n}}(\frac{Z'Z}{n})^{-1}\frac{Z' u}{\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{y_2' Z}{\sqrt{n}}(\frac{Z'Z}{n})^{-1}\frac{Z' y_2}{\sqrt{n}}}$$

For $\frac{\frac{y_2' Z}{\sqrt{n}}(\frac{Z'Z}{n})^{-1}\frac{Z' u}{\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{y_2' Z}{\sqrt{n}}(\frac{Z'Z}{n})^{-1}\frac{Z' y_2}{\sqrt{n}}}$, I want to use the following result: $X_n  \xrightarrow{p} c$ and $Y_n  \xrightarrow{d} _d Y$, then $Y_n + X_n  \xrightarrow{d} Y+c$. Since it is not true that  $X_n  \xrightarrow{p} X$ and $Y_n  \xrightarrow{d} Y$, then $\frac{Y_n}{X_n}  \xrightarrow{d} \frac{Y}{X}$. But I do not know if I'm on the right way. With this in hand, note that if $\pi = \frac{h}{\sqrt{n}}$, using the second equation of the model, we have that $y_{2,i} = \frac{z_{i}' h}{\sqrt{n}} + v_{2,i}$. So:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{Z' u}{\sqrt{n}}  \\
\frac{Z' y_2}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\sum z_i u_i}{\sqrt{n}}  \\
\frac{\sum z_iz_i' h}{n} + \frac{\sum z_i v_{2,i}}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 
0  \\
\frac{\sum z_iz_i' h}{n}
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\sum z_i u_i}{\sqrt{n}}  \\
\frac{\sum z_i v_{2,i}}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{pmatrix}$$

But we also know that $\begin{pmatrix} 
0  \\
\frac{\sum z_iz_i' h}{n}
\end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{p} \begin{pmatrix} 
0  \\
E z_iz_i' h
\end{pmatrix} $ and $\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\sum z_i u_i}{\sqrt{n}}  \\
\frac{\sum z_i v_{2,i}}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{d} \begin{pmatrix} 
\xi_1  \\
\xi_2
\end{pmatrix}\sim N\begin{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0  \\
0
\end{pmatrix}, \Omega \otimes Ez_i z_i'  
\end{pmatrix} $

So that

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{Z' u}{\sqrt{n}}  \\
\frac{Z' y_2}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} 
0  \\
\frac{\sum z_iz_i' h}{n}
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\sum z_i u_i}{\sqrt{n}}  \\
\frac{\sum z_i v_{2,i}}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{d} \begin{pmatrix} 
0  \\
E z_iz_i' h
\end{pmatrix} +  \begin{pmatrix} 
\xi_1  \\
\xi_2
\end{pmatrix}$$

But I have to conclude that

$$\hat{\beta}  \xrightarrow{d} \beta + \frac{(Ez_i z_i' h + \xi_2)'(Ez_iz_i)^{-1}\xi_1}{(Ez_i z_i' h+ \xi_2)'(Ez_iz_i)^{-1}(Ez_i z_i'h +\xi_2)}$$

The impression this gives me is that we are taking the common factor

$$\frac{y_2' Z}{\sqrt{n}}(\frac{Z'Z}{n})^{-1} = \frac{\sum y_{2,i}' z_i}{\sqrt{n}}(\frac{\sum z_i z_i'}{n})^{-1} = \frac{\sum (\frac{z_{i}' h}{\sqrt{n}} + v_{2,i})' z_i}{\sqrt{n}}(\frac{\sum z_i z_i'}{n})^{-1} \to (Ez_i z_i' h + \xi_2)'(Ez_iz_i)^{-1}$$. In this convergence I do not venture to say that it is the convergence in probability, since the term $\xi_2$ appears. Anyway, it seems that it is multiplying in both the numerator and the denominator. So we are implicitly using the result already mentioned above: $X_n  \xrightarrow{p} X$ and $Y_n  \xrightarrow{d} Y$, then $\frac{Y_n}{X_n}  \xrightarrow{d} \frac{Y}{X}$, Because in this particular case $X$ is not a constant.

I am confused. Some help?